# Using a wrapper over google authentificator

Tags: python, security

Is it possible for me to make an app that automatically opens google auth. if a condition is met and then pastes the code in a fillable space on an website ? Does google auth support this kind of stuff?

i didn t find enough info on this topic online

Comment: If I understand you may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run page with `google auth`. And `Selenium` can fill form on page, and later it can get data from web page. Other method is to use GUI framework like `PyQt` and widget `QWebEngine` to simulate Web Browser. Always problem is that Google page uses JavaScript and only real web browser or `QWebEngine` can run it. But other problem can be that Google may have complex system to detect `Selenium` or `QWebEngine` and block it (or show `Captcha`).